# Detect the responsible file for Unknown Plugin in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware-removal, browser-plugin

Chrome 35 on Windows 7 x64 has a plugin that is unknown

[image: uknown plugin chrome]

I run MalwareBytes Anti-Malware in resident mode, and I did a full scan with MS Security Essentials (which does not run resident), nothing came up.

Is it normal to have an unknown plugin on Chrome? If not, how do I go about detecting which file is responsible for this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Type chrome://plugins/ in the address bar and see if you can find anything that remotely resembles something that says Unknown then disable it.  Strangely named plugins may also apply.

Comment: A malware author can mask any code with any name, so I don't think I can rely on this advice for peace of mind.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not usual to have a Unknown plug-in in Chrome. Open `chrome://plugins` and on the top right side of the page there should be a button for Details. Click on it and you will see the location where the plug-ins are stored.

As default the location of the plugins is `C:\Users\"User Name"\AppData\Local\Google\...`

[image: plugins details Chrome]

Comment: I scanned with MSE and MBAM all files listed here. Most of them were actually digitally signed, and a couple that were not I know I installed those extensions. But the "unknown plugin" wasn't listed there.

Comment: If the unknown plugin is not listed there than I do not know how to help you. I would uninstall Chrome (totally) and install it again, just to be sure that it is not some malware. But maybe some plugin was not uninstalled correctly and that is why you get unknown plugin.